# Python getting conditional probabilities of all feature combinations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have a Pandas data frame with some categorical variables. Something like this -

```
>>df
 'a', 'x'
 'a', 'y'
```

Now, I want to return a matrix with the conditional probabilities of each level appearing with every other level. For the data frame above, it would look like -

```
[1, 0.5, 0.5],
[1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 1]
```

The three entries correspond to the levels 'a', 'x' and 'y'.

This is because conditional on the first column being 'a', the probabilities of 'x' and 'y' appearing are 0.5 each and so on.
I have some code that does this (below). However, the problem is that it is excruciatingly slow. So slow that the application I want to use it in times out. Does anyone have any tips to make it faster?

```
df = pd.read_csv('pathToData.csv')
df = df.fillna("null")
cols = 0
col_levels = []
columns = {}
num = 0
for i in df.columns:
cols += len(set(df[i]))
col_levels.append(np.sort(list(set(df[i]))))
for j in np.sort(list(set(df[i]))):
    columns[i + '_' + str(j)] = num
    num += 1

res = np.eye(cols)

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
  for j in range(len(df.columns)):
    if i != j:
        row_feature = df.columns[i]
        col_feature = df.columns[j]
        rowLevels = col_levels[i]
        colLevels = col_levels[j]
        for ii in rowLevels:
            for jj in colLevels:                
                frst = (df[row_feature] == ii) * 1
                scnd = (df[col_feature] == jj) * 1
                prob = sum(frst*scnd)/(sum(frst) + 1e-9)
                frst_ind = columns[row_feature + '_' + ii]
                scnd_ind = columns[col_feature + '_' + jj]
                res[frst_ind, scnd_ind] = prob
```

EDIT: Here is a bigger example:

```
>>df
'a', 'x', 'l'
'a', 'y', 'l'
'b', 'x', 'l'
```

The number of distinct categories here are 'a', 'b', 'x', 'y' and 'l'. Since these are 5 categories, the output matrix should be 5x5. The first row and first column would be how often does 'a' appear conditional on 'a'. This is of course, 1 (as are all the diagonals). The first row and second column is conditional on 'a', what is the probability of 'b'. Since 'a' and 'b' are parts of the same column, this is zero. The first row and third column is the probability of 'x' conditional on 'a'. We see that 'a' appears twice but only once with 'x'. So, this probability is 0.5. And so on.

Comment: Does the dataframe always have two columns? Could you include a bigger example?

Comment: No, the dataframe can have an arbitrary number of columns. Let me construct a bigger example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I approach the problem is to first calculate all unique levels in the dataset. Then loop through a cartesian product of those levels. At each step, filter the dataset to create a subset where condition is True. Then, count the number of rows in the subset where the event has happened. Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b'],
    'col2': ['x', 'y', 'x'],
    'col3': ['l', 'l', 'l']
})

levels = df.stack().unique()

res = defaultdict(dict)
for event, cond in product(levels, levels):

    # create a subset of rows with at least one element equal to cond
    conditional_set = df[(df == cond).any(axis=1)]
    conditional_set_size = len(conditional_set)

    # count the number of rows in the subset where at least one element is equal to event
    conditional_event_count = (conditional_set == event).any(axis=1).sum()

    res[event][cond] = conditional_event_count / conditional_set_size

result_df = pd.DataFrame(res)
print(result_df)

# OUTPUT    
#       a         b    l         x         y
# a  1.000000  0.000000  1.0  0.500000  0.500000
# b  0.000000  1.000000  1.0  1.000000  0.000000
# l  0.666667  0.333333  1.0  0.666667  0.333333
# x  0.500000  0.500000  1.0  1.000000  0.000000
# y  1.000000  0.000000  1.0  0.000000  1.000000
```

I am sure there are other faster methods, but it is the first thing that comes to my mind.